# Problems in accents and special characters with windowless parameter in silverlight

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application (4.0), this has many textbox controls.
When I put this application in my web (MVC) with the param windowless true, this textbox is not recognizing  accents nor special characters when they are Entered with the key

```
"alt" + (number...).
```

This problem occurs only in Chrome and Firefox. In IE it is working perfectly.

If the param windowless is false, it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This depends of the language configuration of your browser, IE use by default the language system, then you would define the correct Doctype and Meta in your app.

With HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="es">
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I have this on my page and the problem persist. 
From what I've read on the internet is a bug in those two browsers that do not pass correctly the culture on silverlight control. But I need a solution!

Any other ideas?